# Pass Symfony project to developer

Tags: symfony, symfony4, development-environment

I have moved my symfony website to production but I need to pass it back to developer. Someone could help me?

I have tried putting app_dev.php but I don't really know how.

**I also have .env like this**

```php
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=****************
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^(localhost|example\.com)$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand. Are you looking for the web profiler toolbar (dev environment, instead of prod)?

Comment: wanted to pass the project back to dev again

Comment: And what's the problem in passing it? Anything not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
APP_ENV=dev APP_DEBUG=1 php bin/console cache:clear
```

This will switch you back to dev mode with debugging on, you can disable that (app_debug=0)

It's the same as moving to prod but in reverse.

Answer (score -1):

For any URL in your app, let's say something like https://url.com/page1, you can try instead to visit https://url.com/app_dev.php/page1 and your dev toolbar should now appear.

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is for symfony 3, but the `.env` format points to the project using flex (could still be 3.4) but the question is tagged symfony4, `app_dev` is gone in 4.

Comment: If `url.com`  points to a production server and this is working, you need to rethink your application. Through the dev environment and Symfony's profiler, the source code of your application is visible to everyone - do you want this to happen?

Comment: @NicoHaase How do I know if my application is in production or developer mode?